# Working of pointers and parameters passing by reference in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, parameters

i have a very weak C programming background, i've just re-started to code in C after studying it at school at very basic level.

I'm doing exercises with pointers to understand how well i grasp them, and i'd like to write a very simple C function that takes 3 parameters, one string, its dim and another string and then inverts them.

My code is as follows:

```
void inverter (char* cstringa, int dim, char* inversion) {
    printf("%d\n", dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        cstringa++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        *inversion = *cstringa;
        printf("%c", *inversion);
        inversion++;
        cstringa--;
    }
}
```

In the main:

```
char stringa1[11] = {'A', 'l', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'o', '\0'};
    char* pstringa1 = stringa1;

    char inversione[strlen(stringa1)];
    inversione[0] = '\0';
    char* pinversione = inversione;

    inverter(stringa1, strlen(stringa1), inversione);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(inversione); i++) {
        printf("%c", *pinversione);
        pinversione++;
    }
```

I expect this code to invert my strings (string1=cstringa, its dim=dim, string2=inversion), but it doesn't do that, since values are not stored in inversione as i expected when i gave him the memory address of the first cell of inversione. Why does this happen?

I also noticed that, when i print the inverted string character by character in the inverter function, it doesn't print the last letter 'A', although dimensions and loop settings are both correct. Why?

Thanks for your patience.

I expected to get the inversion of the first string in output and the parameters passing by reference running ok.

Comment: I suggest you use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.

Comment: There are lots of problems with this code.  For one thing, do you understand that `strlen` does not count the terminating null character?  So your array is too small, and you're writing past the end of it.  Also, it's almost always wrong to call `strlen` in a loop test (unless the string length may actually change inside the loop).  You wouldn't recalculate the length of the string each time through the loop if you were doing it by hand, right?  So why does your code do it?  And don't count on the compiler moving it for you.  In many cases it can't.

Comment: @TomKarzes Hi. Well, i don't want to count the terminating null character in fact. I want to ignore him, since otherwise it would insert it at the beginning of the string while inverting it.

Comment: @AlessandroArgentini Sure, but then how do you intend to null-terminate the result?  You still need space for it, right?  Unless the result is shorter than the original string.  If it's not null-terminated, then it's not a normal C string, and you can't use the `%s` format specifier in `printf` (unless you bound the length).

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, you're right. I had completely forgotten about terminating the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you advanced `cstringa++;` to point to the terminator, so you need to move `cstringa--;` to the *beginning* of the second loop.

Another problem is using `strlen(inversione)` where you haven't set a final terminator, so that needs to be added into the function too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inverter (char* cstringa, int dim, char* inversion) {
    printf("%d\n", dim);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        cstringa++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        cstringa--;        // reposition
        *inversion = *cstringa;
        printf("%c", *inversion);
        inversion++;
    }
    *inversion = 0;       // terminate
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char stringa1[11] = {'A', 'l', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'o', '\0'};
    char* pstringa1 = stringa1;

    char inversione[strlen(stringa1) + 1];   // allow for terminator
    inversione[0] = '\0';
    char* pinversione = inversione;

    inverter(stringa1, strlen(stringa1), inversione);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(inversione); i++) {
        printf("%c", *pinversione);
        pinversione++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
ordnasselA
ordnasselA
```

Comment: Note the code would be easier to type (and to read) with `char stringa1[] = "Alessandro";`